# cordova plugin statusbar not working on Android 13 why?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using cordova-plugin-statusbar to change statusbar background color and statusbar text color but its not working on Android 13

I have added cordova-plugin-statusbar then i have used this code

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', SetStatusBarColor, false);

function SetStatusBarColor() {

    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);

    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#ffffff");

    // Set the status bar text color to black

    StatusBar.styleDefault();

}
```

I need statusbar background color to white and status bar text color to black but its not working on Android 13.
On the other hand its working for Android 12 for first time after installing the app when I relaunch the app statusbar text color not changed into black only background color changed

Comment: Have you tried setting the preferences via the XML instead?

Comment: Yes I have tried

Comment: What's the version of the plugin you're using?

Comment: cordova-plugin-statusbar (version 3.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Any update on this yet? I'm facing the exact same issue. For me setting a timeout inside "deviceready" of about 2 Seconds and doing the StatusBar stuff afterwards works. I modified your example to reflect my solution:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', setTimeout(SetStatusBarColor, 2000), false);

function SetStatusBarColor() {

    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);

    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#ffffff");

    // Set the status bar text color to black

    StatusBar.styleDefault();

}
```

This is however not at all best practise, so I'd like to find a different solution. Would you mind posting an issue on the GitHub repository of the statusbar-plugin? (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)

Comment: Its working for me on Android 13 but still statusbar text color not changing to black

Comment: What device are you testing on? On my Pixel 7a, text color changes work, but background doesn't.

Comment: Realme Narzo 50 a prime

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Setting timeout works but not a great solution. Tried setting "overlaysWebView" to false and changing the order of function calls but nothing worked.

EDIT:
just created an issue for this: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/issues/266

Answer (score 0):

in the config.xml file, set preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" is false, the default value is true,
it works for me.

Comment: is it working as background-color  white and text color black?